# In backbone.js how to fire view unload event?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I have view and i want to fire one event when view unloaded.

```
Backbone.View.extend({
    initializer : function() { 
        // Constructor
    },
    render : function() {
        // My render logic.
    }
})
```

Now how to fire one event when above view unloaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `remove` method from Backbone.View as:

```
remove: function () {

    this.trigger('view:unload'); //Whatever event name

    Backbone.View.prototype.remove.call(this); //Important
},
```

It is important to call the original function to delete correctly the view.

Comment: I added below function, event didn't fire.
remove : function(){
   console.log("Datqa")
   Backbone.View.prototype.remove.call(this); //Important
  }

Comment: @HitulMistry do you mean that you didn't see any log on your console? In that case, your View is not being remove correctly. Check your code to find the memory leak

Comment: Am i need to remove view ? Do you know what happen if i not remove view and just render another view.

Comment: @HitulMistry Bad things happens: http://andrewhenderson.me/tutorial/how-to-detect-backbone-memory-leaks/ http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/03/19/backbone-js-and-javascript-garbage-collection/ http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you can do that. You may want to find a workaround using

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', myFunction);
```